# Remove vertical space between text and image

Tags: html

It's my first time learning HTML. I'd like to know how to remove the vertical space/gap between the text "De Mare" and the image below it such that the text is directly above the image without any space.

```
<h2 style="font-family:pristina;">De Maré</h2>
<img src="de mare/chandelier.jpg" width="35" height="35">
```

Comment: If you hit F12 in your browser, it opens up this inspector window. Then you can hit the arrow thing and click on an element to get a diagram of what it is and what is around it - including things like margin and padding boxes. Then you can see where that comes from and remove it with css like `some_element { margin-bottom: 0; }`. repeat for surrounding elements and you can get an idea of what is going on  and where the space comes from (margin can be a bit tricky btw because adjacent margin boxes will collapse into one, so gotta check all surrounding stuff too).

Comment: May I suggest that you add a screenshot showing the gap you mention in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
<h2 style="font-family:pristina;margin:0;">De Maré</h2>
<img src="de mare/chandelier.jpg" width="35" height="35">
```

Or you could use CSS to get the job done:

```css
span { 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.83em;
    margin-bottom: 0.83em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-family:pristina;">De Maré</span><br>
<img src="de mare/chandelier.jpg" width="35" height="35">
```

And, although I kept it to match yours, make sure to exclude the space in your image URL to get the image to show (unless it's there for a reason).

Answer (score -1):

In your code as you told that you can use two properties that are responsible for the space between the Text and the Images. Along with Width and Depth use the

1. **hspace ="some numeric value" for Horizontal space**
2. **vspace ="some numeric value"  for Vertical space**

   ```
   <h2 style="font-family:pristina;">De Maré</h2>

   <img src="de mare/chandelier.jpg" vspace="20" width="35" height="35">
   ```

Comment: `hspace` and `vspace` have been obsolete for centuries. Perhaps millenia. I'm not sure.